# Enter current directory - mac

Tags: macos, shell

I am on mac and I have a `.command` file which on double click should run my script and hence the application opens.

But the issue is that the application runs from the root folder and not the current folder. How can I automate the way, that the application first automatically enters my `current directory` and then proceed.

Probably some `cd` statement at top of the script

Comment: The script always executes from the path you're calling it from. So if you just double-click the script, it should already be, as you want it. Maybee something else is wrong? Please post some code so we can help you.

Comment: In mac, by default clicking at a script will open it in TextEdit. To run it, we will have to rename it by .command for which it takes root as the main directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` to enter the current directory. And have your respective code after it.

Comment: Definition of a perfect answer. Just add this line before the script-executing command and you are good to go. Thanks!